# Why is calling a filter from code behind faster than with data binding with a View Model?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I've got a rather interesting case here. I have a DataGrid which is bound to an `ICollectionView` of "Tickets." I'm trying to implement some pretty basic filtering of the data in the DataGrid. I was originally *not* using MVVM for this application and simply reset the `ItemsSource` of the DataGrid with the filter function every time the text changed in the text box. The performance was very good for filtering with about 120 items in the Grid. However, I recently refactored a lot of my code to use MVVM because almost everywhere online mentions that it is the defacto way to build WPF applications. Which is great! I've been able to implement some great stuff with it.

However, my filtering is now abysmal. By abysmal, I mean it takes a few seconds to filter the DataGrid with only about 30 items in it. Here is how I'm handling it now:

```
namespace CSSLabelPrinter.ViewModels
{
    public class TicketViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ICollectionView _tickets;
        public ICollectionView Tickets
        {
            get { return _tickets; }
            set
            {
                _tickets = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Tickets");
            }
        }
        private string _filterText;
        public string FilterText
        {
            get { return _filterText; }
            set
            {
                _filterText = value;
                TicketFilter();
                RaisePropertyChanged("FilterText");
            }
        }
        private Ticket _selectedTicket;
        public Ticket SelectedTicket
        {
            get { return _selectedTicket; }
            set
            {
                _selectedTicket = value;

                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedTicket");
            }
        }
        public void TicketFilter()
        {
            string f = _filterText.ToLower();

            Tickets.Filter = delegate (object item)
            {
                Ticket t = item as Ticket;

                if (t.Ticket_ID.ToString().ToLower().Contains(f) ||
                    t.Client_Name.ToString().ToLower().Contains(f) ||
                    t.Report_Date.ToString().ToLower().Contains(f) )
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            };
            var enumer = Tickets.GetEnumerator();
            if(enumer.MoveNext())
                SelectedTicket = (Ticket)enumer.Current;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, 
               new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

In my TicketView, I have the following:

```
<TextBox x:Name="SearchBox" Grid.Column="1" Margin="8,4,0,3"   materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Filter Tickets" 
                                     materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.DecorationVisibility="Hidden" BorderThickness="0"
                                     Text="{Binding FilterText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                                     
                                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                     Focusable="True" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
    <DataGrid
            Grid.Row="1"
            Name="TicketGrid"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Tickets}"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" RowHeight="30"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            SelectionUnit="FullRow"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTicket, Mode=TwoWay}"
            RowHeaderWidth="0">
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ticket No." Binding="{Binding Ticket_ID}"
                                    />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Client_Name}"
                                    />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Problem Type" Binding="{Binding Problem_Type_List}"
                                    />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Report Date" Binding="{Binding Report_Date}"
                                    />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Asset Number" Binding="{Binding Selected_Asset_Number}"
                                    />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

However, this seems to be running very slow. However, if I comment out `TicketFilter();` from FilterText.set, and instead call `TicketFilter()` from my Code Behind, the performance gets better by a few seconds.

```
private void SearchBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
   TicketViewModel vm = this.DataContext as TicketViewModel;
   vm.TicketFilter();
}
```

This is a very slight change, but it seems that the first way makes more sense in MVVM. Unfortunately, even with only 30 items, there is still a second or two delay after entering and deleting one or two characters in the TextBox. Originally, I was handling the binding and the filtering from the codebehind entirely, and that performance was nearly instantaneous. My question is: why does the Code Behind way work more quickly than the "MVVM" way? And relatedly, am I doing something incorrectly in my ViewModel or View which is causing performance to be low?

Comment: You need to take some timings of your VM code and see where the time is being spent. Otherwise it's just guesses. Did you also use that Filter delegate when you were doing all of the filtering in code behind, or was that added when you refactored into the ViewModel?

Comment: Yes, the filter functions are nearly identical. The only difference is that now the search text is from a member variable within the class, and before it was passed in from the TextBox event handler.

Comment: I've done some timing of the various elements in the function, and it definitely spends the most time processing the if statement withing the Filter delegate.